Batch scripting- check if key exists in list/array
I am making a batch script where I'm copying around some directories. At one point the user has to make a decision which file he wants to copy from a certain directory.
When the selection is made by the user, I want to check if the number entered is actually in the list of files. Making sure, that if the users enters something false, it will ask the prompt again.
For testing purposes I made the following script:
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "files="
set count=0

REM show a list of files in a directory
for %%f in ("C:\Windows\*") do (
    set /a count+=1
    echo !count!. %%~nxf
    set "files[!count!]=%%f"
)

REM prompt the user to make a choice
set /p "selection=Select a file: "

REM I need something over here that does something like...
if defined !files[%selection%]! echo file exists (defined)
if not !files[%selection%]=="" echo file exists (quote)
if %selection% in !files! echo file exists (in)

exit /b

If I run the script and choose a file that exists, I get the exact same returns as when I choose a file that doesn't.
I already found a lot of answers where I can check if the value exists in a list, but I can't seem to find such an answer for the key. Some answers suggest to check for !files[%selection%]=="" but for some reason this always equals to true. The first option always equals to false and the last idea throws an error.
My question is: Can I check if a specific key (in my case an integer) exists in a list? In this case I don't care what the value is (could be anything).

if defined !files[%selection%]!, is wrong. To check if a variable is defined, you check its name, not its value! Try if defined files[%selection%] instead. There is also a typo here if not !files[%selection%]=="" and there is almost no chance, once corrected, that !files[%selection%]! will ever =="". Perhaps you meant if not "!files[%selection%]!" == "".

You could make a dynamic choice menu which would keep you from having to do all the extra logic for checking the users selection.

just to complete Compo's comment: if ... in ... syntax simply does not exist in cmd/batch.

You could also do something simple like if %selection% GTR 0 if %selection% LEQ %count% ........

@Compo I'll try that tomorrow. If it solves my problem, please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the solution.

@Squashman can you elaborate? I found a gist  but I'm not sure if that is what you are referring to. https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/4638781

@Jelmer, I am not submitting an answer which essentially tells you information available within the output from if /?. It shows use with ==, comparison operators, and defined. It even states that "it takes an environment variable name".
